# Java API to connect with Share Point Server

Tags: java, api, sharepoint

I will want to know any paid or open source **Java Api** to connect with the **Share Point Server** .

I just google and found [Share Point Java API](https://code.google.com/p/java-sharepoint-library/)

But when i tried to run a simple Demo Code it not worked i also added a bug in google code but no reply.
Any one else used any Paid or Open source Api please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do, but I would recommend that you look at the built-in Web services provided by SharePoint itself.  They can easily be called by Java, and allow you do query items in a library, create new libraries, delete items, upload files, etc.  You can find out more on [Microsoft's site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries available.

**Reference :**

https://code.google.com/p/sharepoint-wsdl/

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/connectors/sharepoint/current.html

We can use SharePoint Web Services for connecting from java.

**Reference :**

http://www.infoq.com/articles/swanson-moss-web-services.

http://techiehojae.blogspot.in/2009/10/invoking-sharepoint-web-services.html